# Read data from STDIN specific number of times

Tags: ruby

I am writing a code that is supposed to read from STDIN exactly n number of times.So lets say 3 times.What is the best way to do that ?

I tried this

```
counter = 0
while sentence = gets.chomp && counter < 3 do
 ...
 counter += 1
end
```

but for some strange reason, sentence variable inside loop is Boolean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below:

```
n.times { sentence = gets.chomp }
```

or

```
n.times do 
  sentence = gets.chomp
  # your code here
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence. The line:

```
while sentence = gets.chomp && counter < 3 do
```

Is being interpretted as

```
while sentence = ( gets.chomp && counter < 3 ) do
```

So, you could do this:

```
while ( sentence = gets.chomp ) && counter < 3 do
```

---

That explains why you got `true` or `false` values into `sentence`, and the third option should fix this, so your code is very close to working. However, it is probably more usual in Ruby to see solutions like Babai's